# how to refer one jsp page on another jsp page?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I want to have references on my welcomePage.jsp page to other jsp pages - loginPage.jsp and registerPage.jsp. I tried to use simple   like this:

```
<head>
<title>${title}</title>
</head>
<body>  
  <jsp:include page="header.jsp"/>      
  <jsp:include page="_menu.jsp" />

  <h1>Welcome to the page!</h1>
  <a href="registerPage.jsp">Register</a>           
  <p>or</p>
  <a href="loginPage.jsp">Log In</a>
  <p>if you already have an account</p>

  <jsp:include page="footer.jsp"/>
</body>
</html>
```

But I keep getting HTTP Status 404 The requested resource is not available.

I also tried  but as a result the contents of the pages I was referencing too just apperead on this welcomePage. Although I need them to be accessible through links only. 
All the mentioned files are located in WEB-INF/pages.
This is my first project with Spring MVC so any help is welcomed.

Comment: in spring mvc URL may  different so try to use jstl tags or use apache tiles

Answer (score 2):

Suppose, in your configuration, you have set the location of views e.g. `/WEB-INF/view/` where you put all of your .jsp files - `loginpage.jsp, registerPage.jsp` etc. Now, you can simply access the location of view i.e. `/WEB-INF/view/` via `pageContext.servletContext.contextPath`.

```
//For example
href="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/loginpage"
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to go to a controller first, than call a ModelAndView in this controller. This also keeps the relations clear between the JSP files.

To apply this your controller class should be like this:

```
@Controller
public class LoginPageController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView printLoginPage() {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("loginPage");
        return modelAndView;
    }
}
```

You can also pass parameters from a JSP page to another by going through a controller method.

Comment: Thank you! I will try this out.

Comment: You are most welcome, I hope it will solve your problem! @dark_matter88